# Sails.js cannot update display gallery for updating into mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to update a program for updating and inserting into mongodb, but I keep getting an error. Let me paste the relevant code here, and I hope to get some help.

**PosProductVariant.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : true,
    attributes: {
        // unique name identifier
        name : { type: 'text', unique : true , required : true },
        product : { model : 'PosCustomProduct' },
        additionalPrice : { type : 'integer', defaultsTo: 0 },
        // assets
        display         : { model : 'CmsProductVariant' },
        // store referrer
        store : { model : 'SystemStore' }
    }
};
```

**CmsProductVariant.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : true,
    attributes: {
        // custom product variant reference
        product : { model : 'PosProductVariant' },
        // custom title
        title : { type : 'string' },
        gallery : { type : 'array' , defaultsTo : [] }, // main gallery
    }
};
```

**PosProductController.js**

```
    module.exports = {
        updatePricing : function(req,res,next){
            // get pricing parameters
            var pricing = req.allParams(),
                query = {};
            // parameters violation
            if(!pricing.additionalPrice)
                return res.badRequest();
            // compose query
            for(var attr in pricing){
                if(attr !== 'additionalPrice' && _.isArray(pricing[attr])){
                    query[attr] = pricing[attr];
                }
            }
            sails.log.verbose('pricing parameter');
            sails.log.verbose(pricing);
            sails.log.verbose('update query');
            sails.log.verbose(query);
            PosProductVariant.update(query,{
                additionalPrice : pricing.additionalPrice,
display : pricing.display.gallery
            })
            .then(function(_variant){
                if(!_variant) throw 'Cant update Variant';
                res.ok();
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                sails.log.error(error);
                res.serverError(error);
            });
        }
    };
```

**pricing.html**

```
<form class="grid-fluid grid-parent" name="pricingForm" ng-if="isDefined(product)"
    ng-disabled="isProcessing" ng-submit="updatePricing()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group grid-50" ng-repeat="(attr, options) in product.attributes">
        <label>{{attr}}</label>
        <select multiple ng-model="pricing[attr]" class="form-control" ng-options="option for option in options" required></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group grid-100">
        <label>add price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="pricing.additionalPrice" placeholder="add price" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group grid-100">
        <carousel class="bg-dark">
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in pricing.display.gallery" active="slide.active" index="$index">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.gallery}}" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <a class="button button-error button-labeled"
                        ng-click="removeItem(pricing.display.gallery,$index)">
                        <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-trash-a"></i></span>
                        delete image
                    </a>
                </div>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
        <hr/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>tambahan galeri</label>
            <file-uploader class="form-control"
                image-width="{{galleryConfigs.width}}"
                image-height="{{galleryConfigs.height}}"
                image-crop-width="{{galleryConfigs.width}}"
                image-crop-height="{{galleryConfigs.height}}"
                max-size="5000"
                allowed-extensions="png,jpeg,jpg"
                result-model="addGallery">
            </file-uploader>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- action -->
    <div class="form-group grid-100">
       <hr/>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-labeled"
            ng-disabled="pricingForm.$invalid || pricingForm.$pristine || isProcessing" >
            <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-paper-airplane"></i></span>
            Update Pricing
        </button>
        <button class="button button-default button-labeled pull-right" role="action"
            ng-click="goBack()" ng-disabled="isProcessing">
            <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-android-close"></i></span>
            Back
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And controller pricing.js

```
var store = {},
        id = $stateParams.modelId,
        filter = {};

    // get current active store
    store = authService.getCurrentStore($scope);
    if(!store){
        // session expired
        $scope.$emit(GLOBAL_EVENTS.SYSTEM.STORE.SESSION_TIMEOUT);
        return;
    }

    // init scope
    $scope.product = {};
    $scope.pricing = {
        display: {
            gallery: []
        }
    };

    moduleConfigResolver.syncStoreConfig(store.id)
    .then(function(STORE_CONFIG){
        // get gallery image size configs
        $scope.galleryConfigs = {
            height : [STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_ZOOM_HEIGHT,
                STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_GALLERY_HEIGHT,
                STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT],
            width : [STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_ZOOM_WIDTH,
                STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_GALLERY_WIDTH,
                STORE_CONFIG.POS_PRODUCT_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH]
        };
    });

    // add gallery image
    $scope.addGallery = function(imageSrc){
        if(!angular.isArray(imageSrc) || imageSrc.length < 3)
            return;

        $scope.pricing.display.gallery.push({
            zoom      : imageSrc[0],
            gallery   : imageSrc[1],
            thumbnail : imageSrc[2]
        });
    };

    // if has url params
    if(id){
        dataProvider.CustomProduct.get({'id':id}).$promise
        .then(function(_product_customize){
            $scope.product = angular.copy(_product_customize);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            $log.error(error);
        });
```

It looks to me that the form does not submit data gallery, as the parameters are printed as undefined/null in my posproductcontroller and get an error.

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "CmsProductVariant",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "hashedPassword": [
      {
        "display": CmsProductVariant,
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what is my problem with my code? Help me please Sir?